# div Img background doesn't work in my CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

So this is my CSS code:

```
#plaatje {
background-image: url('Plaatjes\slider_two_temp.jpg');
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

}

And it won't work at all. I placed the picture in the same map as my HTML file.

Comment: Is your CSS directly in ur HTML file or is the CSS file in the same directory as your image? Use the browser inspector to see what is happening

Comment: The relative path in the CSS is relative to the CSS file, not to the HTML file. Does that answer your question? If not, can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Provide code or elaborate the question so that others can contribute on your problem.

Comment: Change the backslash in the filepath to a regular slash like `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks fine do a couple of things!

First check whether the id **#plaatje** is referenced correctly? also check for the path of css and html file

second check the path for your image the path you give in css is relative to your css file you should enter the correct path! if you're not sure about that use absolute path e.g  `background-image: url('http://localhost/Plaatjes/images/slider_two_temp.jpg');` but **beware** if you have a large application you might then need to change all the paths for live server!

the last thing you could do is to hit **ctrl+f12** for inspect element there you can what actually is wrong with your code!

also check your console by hitting **ctrl+f12** many times the issues is that we are not using the correct path for our files which results in **File not found** error

if none of above works share your html code , css code so we can have a look at it
hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this i think

```css
#plaatje {
  background-image:url('http://investorplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/google-amazon-goog-amzn-stock-300x200.jpg');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karanmehta786/rd1yezc2/

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is you can enclose your id details in a style tag and you can make id name to any tag like paragraph tag and after that all your code will be alright.

```
<style>
 #plaatje{
    background-image: url('Plaatjes/slider_two_temp.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    }
</style>
    <p id="plaatje"></p>
```

If you want to try this by

```
 <div id="plaatje"></div>
```

it will also work fine for div tag